# explicit specialization is using partial specialization syntax

Tags: c++, templates

I am attempting to use this vector I found through a tutorial which displays the code as functioning. However when I attempt to use it in my project it returns the error "error C3211: 'vector::vecarg': explicit specialization is using partial specialization syntax, use template <> instead"

Just the section with the error

```
template< class ta_a >
class vecarg
{
    const ta_a& Argv;
public:
    inline vecarg(const ta_a& A) : Argv(A) {}
    inline const float Evaluate(const int i) const
    {
        return Argv.Evaluate(i);
    }
};

template< class ta_a>
class vecarg< const float >
{
    const ta_a& Argv;
public:
    inline vecarg(const ta_a& A) : Argv(A) {}
    inline const float Evaluate(const int i) const
    {
        return Argv;
    }
};

template< class ta_a >
class vecarg< const int >
{
    const ta_a& Argv;
public:
    inline vecarg(const ta_a& A) : Argv(A) {}
    inline const float Evaluate(const int i) const
    {
        return (float)Argv;
    }
};
```

If I correct this error by changing to

```
template< >
class vecarg< const float >
{
    const ta_a& Argv;
```

then the error changes to "identifier 'ta_a' is undefined"

Any suggestions on a solution are highly appreciated.

Comment: `const ta_a& Argv;` should be `const float& Argv;`

Comment: Does the error message not _literally_ tell you how to fix it?

Comment: _"Edit: Once fixed a new error arises."_  Don't do that. One question per question.

Comment: The code in your "edit" is unrelated. Please roll back and post a new question (and in that question you need to show how `assignment` was instantiated for the case giving the error; prefeably post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
template< class ta_a>
class vecarg< const float >
```

This is an error because `vecarg` only has one template parameter: it can be specialized for that parameter, but then there are no more template parameters. But this code tries to write two parameters, `ta_a` and `float`.

The error messages talk about "partial specialization" because a specialization introduced by `template<class T>` must be partial (it's not full because it still has parameter `T`).

The code for a full specialization would be:

```
template<>   // zero parameters which have not been specialized
class vecarg< const float >
{
    const float& Argv;
public:
    vecarg(const float& A) : Argv(A) {}
    const float Evaluate(const int i) const
    {
        return Argv;
    }
};
```

I removed the redundant `inline` specifiers. You'll need to make similar changes to the other specialization attempt.

If the author of this code claimed that it compiled, he/she must have had some pretty wacky compiler.